# @font-face : flash of STYLED text on Firefox (FOST)

Tags: css, firefox, font-face

---

I know that the FOUT issue on @font-face in Firefox (and other...) was treated again and again but I'm not here for that.

I currently encounter a very strange issue, when I browse pages of my site, I see **FOST (Flash of Styled Text)**: The page is displayed for one second, everything is OK, texts (@ font-face) for some milliseconds disappear and then reappear in the same way.

**Here is my @font-face declaration:**

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'DINWeb-Bold';
  src: url('/fonts/DINWeb-Bold.eot');
  src: local('☺'),
         url('/fonts/DINWeb-Bold.woff') format('woff'), url('/fonts/DINComp-Bold.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

**Config :**

- Mac OSX 10.8.2
- Firefox 13.0

*(NB: I did not have the font on my local computer)*

Can someone enlighten me on this mystery?!

Thank you very much

Comment: Have you got the page somewhere on the web so that we can take a look? I wouldn’t buy the font just to help with the issue. Also please specify Firefox version(s) and platform(s) used in testing.

Comment: Hi @JukkaK.Korpela, thanks for your answer. The site is in development on our servers and is not yet reached from the outside but it should be online soon I would put the link here, if it can help. For the config, I just edit the post.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my **"FOST"** problem importing webfont in a **Typekit Kit** ([fontshop](http://www.fontshop.com/) permits it, thank you god). It seems that the Typekit's integration script includes something to annihilate any FOUC effect, so  ...

> The default embed code is simple and easy to use. It does a good job of hiding the flash of unstyled text by blocking rendering while loading.

Well, it worked for me, but I'm curious to know if there is another solution without going through Typekit. **Maybe Google's WebFont Loader?**